# Why doesn't the two way binding work for me in Angular 10?

Tags: html, angular10

I'm working on a little login project, and there is one thing that doesn't work for me. I want to do two way binding for my userID and password, and it just doesn't work. (I'm working in the login component, so not in the app component).

HTML:

```
<div class="loginstuff">
    <label>Log in a.u.b.</label><br>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userID" /><br>
    <div>user: {{ userID }}</div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="password" /><br>
    <div>pw: {{ password }}</div>
    <button (click)="Login();">Login</button><br>
    
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedRole" (focus)="RoleSelection('User')" checked/>User
    
    <input type="radio" name="radiobutton" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedRole" (focus)="RoleSelection('Admin')"/>Admin<br>
    
    <div>your selected role is {{selectedRole}}</div>
    <a [routerLink]="['/registration']" (click)="GoToRegistration()">Registreren</a>    
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

TS

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  selectedRole='User';

  userID = '';
  password = '';

  registration = '';
  
  RoleSelection(role){
    this.selectedRole = role;
  }
  Login(){
    
    if(this.selectedRole === 'User'){
      console.log(this.userID, this.password);
    }
    else{
      this.router.navigate(['/adminpage'])
    }
    
  }

}
```

And this is what it looks like:
[Login project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ianyI.png)

I added the user: and pw: to check if the two way binding is working. Whatever I type in the userID and password fields is supposed to show behind the user: and pw:, but it doesn't. As you can see, I did the two way binding with my radio buttons and it works (on the image you can see it shows "you selected role is User, User comes from a variable. PS: I know the variable is already bound to the value "User" but that's just the default value. When I click on the admin radio button it changes to "Admin" so I know it works). I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, since I do the exact same thing with the radio buttons and they work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use FormGroup, it supports the two way binding for forms and much more, like validation. Pass a FormGroup to your `<div class="loginstuff" [formGroup]="yourFormGroup">`. And for your inputs:
`<input type="text" formControlName="login"/>`.

And in your `.ts` class:

```js
const form = new FormGroup({
  login: new FormControl(),
  password: new FormControl()
});
```